# How do I transfer a data to another domain without using a URL parameter?

Tags: authentication, redirect, cross-domain, access-token

Users become members through the app domain.
`app.example.com` this is the URL we used to sign up for the app. After the register is completed, I need to redirect the user to the domain that he/she has determined (eg. `dynamic.example.com`.)
After the registration process on `app.example.com` is completed, I keep the access token in the browser local storage. However, since the user will continue on this site `dynamic.example.com`, when I redirect there, I lose the token.

I think it is not safe to send the token as a URL parameter like `dynamic.example.com?token=blabla`. How should I configure it here? Should we manage this on the front end or the back end?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the same domain, `example.com`, you could use Cookies to send that data around, just remember to configure `sameSite` and `secure` properties to allow it to work. If you face another wall with it, try Mozilla documentation about cookies. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies